# Sorting user defined structure in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a data structure of the following form:

```
struct E{
 unsigned k;
 unsigned c;
 unsigned v[100];
};

main()
{
 vector<E*> vecE;
 E e1;
 e1.k=10; e1.c=20; e1.v[0]=30; e1.v[1]=31;
 vecE.push_back(&e1);
 E e2;
 e2.k=101; e2.c=28; e2.v[0]=82; e2.v[1]=32;
 vecE.push_back(&e2);
 //sort vecE by E.k of the structure
}
```

I have a large vecE containing thousands of objects of type E. I need to sort vecE again and again. What is the fastest way by which I can sort vecE in-memory -- here vecE is sorted on E.k. One of the ways by which one can do the same is by building priority queue. But priority will be rather expensive due to insertions. Is there some other fast way by which I can sort vecE on "k".

Also after sorting and outputting the results to the user I want to delete the vecE entirely..but I can not do so as it consists of pointers to E. How can I destroy vecE completely, so that even values pointed to by E are deleted.

The gcc version that I am using is: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.4-6ubuntu2) 4.6.4

Comment: How do you compare two Es?

Comment: @Golazo I compare the two E's based on E1.k and E2.k. That is I do the sorting on "k"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `E` is quite a big structure, you should have a `vector<E*>`, so that swapping elements is as fast as swapping a single integer. Then you can use either `sort` or `stable_sort` from the standard header `<algorithm>` (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/).

```
vector<E*> vecE;
sort(vecE.begin(),vecE.end(),compE);
```

with:

```
bool compE(E* first,E* second)
{
    return (first->k < second->k);
}
```

At the end delete the elements this way:

```
for(auto e: vecE)
{
    delete e;
}
```

You don't need to delete the vector itself, because it has automatic storage duration, and it will be destroyed at scope exit.

Answer (score 1):

```
class cmp{  // Function object to pass to std::sort algorithm
public:
    bool operator()(const E &a, const E &b)
    {
        return a.k > b.k;
    }
};
int main()
{ 
    vector<E> a(10);
    cmp comparator;
    sort(begin(a), end(a), comparator); 
    return 0;
}
```